# Same Google Verification tag for multiple domains

Tags: google-search-console, google-tag-manager

I have registered an HTML google `<meta />` tag in my production webpage provided by the  Google Search Console, but we have other 3 environments to verify.

If I create a new property in the Google Search Console, I'd get **the same** `<meta />` tag for every  new property (url).

My pages shared the code since they are just different environments and thus different urls. Like so:

```
myPage.azurewebsites.net --- successfully verified in Google Search Console
myPage-dev.azurewebsites.net --- can't verify
myPage-test.azurewebsites.net --- can't verify
myPage-uat.azurewebsites.net --- can't verify
```

Since the code is shared (commit may vary ofc) between all the environments the unique `<meta />` tag is already present in all the urls.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!-- Google Verification Tag -->
      <meta name="google-site-verification" content="my-unique-google-code-here" /> // same for all the urls
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      // etc
```

However if I try to verify them in the Google Search Console I can't.

[image]

**Possible solution?**

We were thinking of creating one  unique `<meta />` tag per page but I can't find a way to do this. I'd get the same for all the urls in my account.

Comment: Do you have control over the meta tag? of the mypage-dev.example.com myPage-test.example.com etc? If you do they should use the same tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search console uses your google account or email and allows you to have an unlimited number of sites and each site to have an unlimited number of users/google accounts that can collaborate.

### The Search Console tag is the same tag for all domains you own

If you have control over the <meta name="google-site-verification" content="owner"> and are the owner they normally match.

If you are collaborating, then you need to be added as a user.

### Two accounts and two email addresses

You need to log into the account you want to add a user to and add a user, (your other email). Then log into your account where you have been added and accept the role you have been given.

### A domain can have more than one site.

IE **john.example.com** **tim.example.com** or perhaps **example.com/john/** and/or **example.com/tim** which can **have their own search console account** and do not collaborate. **Unless they give each other access.**

**In this case you want to collaborate:** You and the others want to see the same information for the entire site. or should I say you and others want to see the same information for your portion of a shared host.

Who is the owner? Their <meta name="google-site-verification" content="owner" > should be used. Although I believe in the past before the ability to add additional users: It may have been possible by verifying via HTML file upload to appear to have two accounts on one property, but it may have removed the prior accounts' access. Not set up a collaboration and when the site is verified what took place before the verification is not shown.

**To collaborate add a user. If you are taking over the account remove the other meta tag.**

[image]

Under the settings of the user, there is a user and permissions selection. Go there and add a user and assign their role.

### Meta tag is for home page, child pages are automatic.

The meta tag method is for the home page, child pages of the site are automatically included. So having your tag on example.com/mypage would exclude your page from who has the tag on example.com/ and work as if there two sites on the same domain which do not see the information from the other sites on the domain.

IE if you added <meta name="google-site-verification" content="your-tag" > to mysite.wordpress.com or sites.google.com/mysite/ you would not have any information or control over any other section of the domain, but would to the child pages ... mysite.wordpress.com/child-page or sites.google/mysite/child-page

### Via analytics

**Another access point for shared hosting environments** is the analytics.google.com ... many shared domains offer or allow you to turn on analytics and that can be used to verify your portion of the share domain in search console.

Google sites is using the analytics method to provide search console. Others and maybe azurewebsites.net is doing the same. Because google is doing it this way others may consider it best practice by default.

Comment: Hey Wayne, thanks for the long explanation! What it's not yet clear to me if I can generate different tags with the same account or all the generated meta tags will be always the same but they can be used in all of my different urls (properties in GSC)

Comment: The tags you create in the search console are all the same, I've never seen them change. You place it on the site and then verify the site ... if you create a new email account and create a new search console as that user their tags would be different; you may want to create a new "owners" account for https://www.google.com/business/ for the purpose of google maps and etc, the business account allows you to manage the google knowledge including hour of operation, phone number, etc that appears on the side of the search for a company name and within maps. I

Comment: So in can I decide to use the unique tag, I should be able to verify all my different urls with the same tag, right? Thanks again

Comment: I have added the GA4 tag to each page. I'm now trying to figure out how to verify them in the GSC lol.